# Finding IP Address of Oracle Database Server

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Hey all so I am trying to find the IP address of an Oracle 11g Database server. I am hosting it from my desktop PC and would like to be able to access it from other places.

I have SQL*plus installed and when I connect to my database via SQL*plus command console and then execute `select utl_inaddr.get_host_address from dual;` It returns `fe80::f1a9:4392:5e20:2adc%11` which appears to be an IPv6 address. I need an IPv4 address in order to do what I want.

After browsing I seem to notice that `select sys_context('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS') from dual;` returns IPv4 addresses (or at least should) however it returns nothing for me.

Do I need to do some modifications to my oralisteners or something to make this work? It appears as though my database is not accessible unless I am on the same box that is hosting it.

I can post any additional data / configs if it will help to solve this issue. Any advice on how to get this database properly setup to be accessible remotely would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The address of the server will be the address of your PC for others on your network. If you're trying to access it from outside your local network, then it'll be the IP address of your router and you'll need to forward the appropriate port (usually 1521 for Oracle) to your PC. That's assuming there's only one NAT layer between you and the Internet.

Comment: What if I myself do not use a router in my home? I am connected directly to the wall.

Comment: @Blued00d Assuming there's no between you and the Internet erforming NAT, then your computer's IP and the IP of our Internet connection is the same, and you'll find http://whatismyip.com invaluable.

Answer (score 0):

Execute this once you login with sqlplus or sqldeveloper

```
SELECT sys_context('userenv','server_host') FROM DUAL;
```